# tomcat 7 - org.apache.jasper.JasperException contains invalid expression(s): javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression

Tags: jsp, tomcat, jstl, el

In one of my jspx, the jstl expression below:

```
<c:set var="colors" value="${['#1abc9c', '#e74c3c', '#3498db', '#F4D03F', '#9b59b6', '#bdc3c7', '#244F75']}" />
```

is throwing the below error on tomcat 7:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException:
>   /WEB-INF/views/proj/abc/show.jspx (line: 90,
>   column: 119) "${['#1abc9c', '#e74c3c', '#3498db', '#F4D03F',
>   '#9b59b6', '#bdc3c7', '#244F75']}" contains invalid expression(s):
>   javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression [${['#1abc9c',
>   '#e74c3c', '#3498db', '#F4D03F', '#9b59b6', '#bdc3c7', '#244F75']}]

I have added the following in my tomcat 7 conf catalina.properties as per other threads but it doesn't help.

```
org.apache.el.parser.SKIP_IDENTIFIER_CHECK=true
```

Well it is working for my colleagues on tomcat 8.5. Do I really need to upgrade or am I missing something?

Comment: Try adding JSTL library is included within `$CATALINA_HOME/lib` or within your `WEB-INF/lib` directory. tell me result.  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl/jstl/1.2

Comment: So why aren't you using the same version of Tomcat as your colleagues?

Comment: @EJP I eventually did but I was still curious to know what tomcat 7 does not have.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to:

```
<c:set var="colors" value="${fn:split('#1abc9c,#e74c3c,#3498db,#F4D03F,#9b59b6,#bdc3c7,#244F75', ',')}" />
```